# Fastest way to acquire Cracked red eye orbs?

Tags: dark-souls-2

What is the best/fastest way to acquire cracked red eye orbs?  I'm level 150 and short of dueling other Brotherhood of Blood members I cannot find a way to acquire these.  Dueling doesn't appear to be a very good method because it often takes over five minutes to land a duel.

Comment: Yes! Get more people sinning so I can punish them!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several monsters that drop the orbs:

- Fire Salamanders in the cave under the Cardinal Tower bonfire.
- Polearm wielding hunters in Huntsman's Copse.
- The three Piglets to the right of the Majula Mansion.

The one that has given me the best drop rate is the Fire Salamander.

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkUCy67bgYo) a video of someone farming the little Piglets in Majula.

Also, Titchy Gren (The Brotherhood of Blood guy) sells them for 10,000 souls each in NG+
(As confirmed by @miR, burning an ascetic will not allow you to buy them).

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Can you burn an Acetic at the Titchy Gren Bonfire to get him to sell them in NG? I know it works with some NPCs and doesnt with others.

Comment: I have no reason to believe otherwise, every NPC has to act accordingly to the cicle in place.

Comment: Actually,  I was disappointed to find that burning an ascetic did NOT work. Tried it shortly after reading this.

Comment: That is disappointing, I'll make sure to add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Kill Elana(only once) in the first DLC and bonfire ascetic the first bonfire in the DLC, each ascetic nets you 5 cracked red eye orbs, 3 twinkling, 1 elizabeth mushroom. so basically you're getting almost 100k worth of items for 1 ascetic which you can buy for 7.5k and you dont need to buy any if you pick up all the ascetics throughout the game, youll have plenty to get 99 CREO and 99 twinkling titanite. If you run out of ascetics use the CREO in the chasm of old and get more 1 CREO for 1 Ascetic if you win.

Comment: The only problem is when you get to bonfire intensity 99 which means you can no longer get any CREO. but to think that you're getting 495 of them before you cant anymore, by this point youll cycle through 99 token of spites about 6/7 times so you would have about 200/300 hours on one character before it happens.

Answer (score 0):

A bonfire at 99 intensity will still replenish items, just the number wont increase. Kill elana and the darklurker for ascetic farming. I got 85 CREO in about an hour and a half lats night